# How did Hansel remove his own underwear in Zoolander?

Tags: zoolander

In Zoolander, Zoolander and Hansel have a walk-off, in which they must replicate each other's moves. To win, Hansel performs a seemingly miraculous move: he pulls out his own underwear without taking off his pants. Zoolander fails to copy this move and wedgies himself. Is this actually possible, and if so how? Or did Hansel cheat?

Comment: He uses the same magic Zoolander uses to stop the throwing star with a look. It's parody physics. Perfectly possible in their universe, and by that logic, Hansel did not trick anyone. He was wearing underwear, then removed them exactly as seen on the runway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, this is not possible in real life in the way shown in the film without having velcro or simply having a spare set of underwear shoved into his trousers.

This is a pastiche of how women can (with a little working) remove their bras without taking off the top layer of clothing.

In the film, Hansel is really that good.

Comment: I wonder if he was glad to take them off because he's so hot right now?